# PHP Search Multidimensional Array - Not Associative

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a piece of code that searches one column of 2-D array values and returns the key when it finds it.  Right now I have two functions, one to find a value and return a boolean true or false and another (not working) to return the key.  I would like to merge the two in the sense of preserving the recursive nature of the finding function but returning a key.  I cannot think how to do both in one function, but working key finder would be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = true) {
foreach ($haystack as $item) {
    if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

}

```
function loopAndFind($array, $index, $search){
     $returnArray = array();
     foreach($array as $k=>$v){
           if($v[$index] == $search){   
                $returnArray[] = $k;
           }
     }
     return $returnArray;
```

}`

Sorry, I meant to add an example.  For instance:

```
Array [0]{
[0]=hello
[1]=6
}
[1]
{
[0]=world
[1]=4
}
```

and I want to search the array by the [x][0] index to check each string of words for the search term.  If found, it should give back the index/key in the main array like "world" returns 1

Comment: Could you post an example array highlighting what you would like to match within it? "one column of 2-D array values and returns the key" is not very clear.

Comment: why are you using index in second function?

Comment: I posted an example above and I am not really sure why I am using index.  I think it was supposed to be the index of the second array like Array[0]{[index]=stuff, [1]=words} etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
$array = array(array('hello', 6), array('world', 4));
$searchTerm = 'world';

foreach ($array as $childKey => $childArray) {
    if ($childArray['0'] == $searchTerm) {
        echo $childKey; //Your Result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have all you need in your first function. PHP does the rest:

```
$findings = array_map('in_array_r', $haystack);
$findings = array_filter($findings); # remove all not found
var_dump(array_keys($findings)); # the keys you look for
```

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure I know what you are trying to do.  I need to search through the array one term at a time rather than run the function all at once.  Does that make sense or did I misunderstand your code?  Thanks

Comment: It was not really clear from your question what you want to search and how. You have dropped some functions w/o showing any code how you want to call them, what the input is and what the output should be. If you add that, I'm pretty sure I can make the answer equally clear.